# Aurelia EventAggregator pub/sub order for components

Tags: aurelia

I followed the Aurelia [contact manager tutorial](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/contact-manager-tutorial/8). Short summary issue as follows: `app.html` has 2 components

```
<template>
    <contact-list></contact-list>
    <router-view></router-view> <!-- placeholder to load contact-detail -->
<template>
```

- contact-list: subscribe event ContactViewed (in constructor)
- contact-detail: publish event ContactViewed (in activate)

It is OK if contact-list is init before contact-detail. But when I directly navigate to URL e.g. http://localhost:11414/#/contacts/detail/3, the components are initialized as follow order: contact-detail ctor -> contact-detail activate -> contact-list ctor. That means contact-list cannot capture the first publish event of contact-detail because at the time contact-detail publish event, the contact-list has not subscribed event yet.

How can I control order of pub/sub in this case or are there any solution to fix this?

Comment: My intuition tells me that you've done everything right. You don't have a gist.run demonstrating the issue?